# Initialize an object after it is referenced by an other

Tags: c#, object, initialization

I've got a 2 Dimensional array, which stores fields of a chessboard..

```
private field[,] board = new field[boardsize,boardsize];
```

..now when I initialize them I want to reference to the neighbours of every field, which are partly not initilized yet.

At the moment a use a work-around like this:

```
for(int x = 0; x < boardsize ; x++)
{
  for(int y = 0; y < boardsize ; y++)
  {
    board[x,y] = new field();
  }
}


for(int x = 0; x < boardsize ; x++)
{
  for(int y = 0; y < boardsize ; y++)
  {
    board[x,y].setNeighbours(x, y, board);
  }
}
```

This works fine but I'm interested if its possible to set the neighbours before or at time of the initialisation.

setNeighbour - Method:

```
setNeighbour(int x, int y, field[,])
{
  if(field[x-1,y] != null)
    this.neighbour[0] = field[x-1,y];
  if(field[x-1,y+1] != null)
    this.neighbour[0] = field[x-1,y+1];
  if(field[x,y+1] != null)
    this.neighbour[0] = field[x,y+1];
  if(field[x+1,y+1] != null)
    this.neighbour[0] = field[x+1,y+1];
  if(field[x+1,y] != null)
    this.neighbour[0] = field[x+1,y];
  if(field[x+1,y-1] != null)
    this.neighbour[0] = field[x+1,y-1];
  if(field[x,y-1] != null)
    this.neighbour[0] = field[x,y-1];
  if(field[x-1,y-1] != null)
    this.neighbour[0] = field[x-1,y-1];

}
```

Comment: Post `setNeighbours` code, please. Also, default naming convention for methods in C# is PascalCase, that is, `SetNeighbours`.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not satisfied with your workaround?

Comment: How do you check whether a field is on the edge of the board or not?

Comment: with the if-statement; when the field is null, you know your on the edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
private field[,] board = new field[boardsize,boardsize];

for(int x = 0; x < boardsize ; x++)
{
  for(int y = 0; y < boardsize ; y++)
  {
    if(board[x,y] == null)
        board[x,y] = new field();
    board[x,y].setNeighbours(x, y, board);
  }
}
```

and check initialization of the neighbour in the `setNeighbours()` method the same way:

```
private void setNeighbours(int x, int y, field[,] board)
{
    //Initialize neighbour if not already initialized
    if(board[x+1,y] == null)
       board[x+1,y] = new field();

    //DO SOMETHING... 
}
```

Comment: Why? the creation is set only if the field is null

Comment: True you did check and after that you would set the neighbor property.

Answer (score 1):

I don't Believe it's possible to reference the neighbours since they aren't created yet. You could however add the board as a parameter to the constructor of field and use a property to look up the neighbours when needed later.

Comment: Lazy loading of the neighbors would probably be effective. As most pieces have a very limited move set. The queen would be the only one causing fields all over the place to start loading neighbors.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical problem... Sadly C# doesn't have continuations... They can be simulated (very slowly) through the use of `Thread`s... Yes, it is overkill, and it is only an exercise in programming:

```
public sealed class WaitForReady<T> : IDisposable
{
    public readonly ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            mre.WaitOne();
            return this.value;
        }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
            mre.Set();
        }
    }

    private T value;

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        mre.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion
}

public class Field
{
    public Field[] Neighbours;

    public Field(WaitForReady<Field> me, WaitForReady<Field>[] neighbours)
    {
        me.Value = this;

        Neighbours = new Field[neighbours.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < neighbours.Length; i++)
        {
            Neighbours[i] = neighbours[i] != null ? neighbours[i].Value : null;
        }
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int boardsize = 8;
    Field[,] board = new Field[boardsize, boardsize];

    WaitForReady<Field>[,] boardTemp = null;

    try
    {
        boardTemp = new WaitForReady<Field>[boardsize, boardsize];

        var threads = new Thread[boardsize * boardsize];

        for (int i = 0; i < boardsize; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < boardsize; j++)
            {
                boardTemp[i, j] = new WaitForReady<Field>();
            }
        }

        int k = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < boardsize; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < boardsize; j++)
            {
                var neighbours = new WaitForReady<Field>[8];
                neighbours[0] = i > 0 && j > 0 ? boardTemp[i - 1, j - 1] : null;
                neighbours[1] = i > 0 ? boardTemp[i - 1, j] : null;
                neighbours[2] = i > 0 && j + 1 < boardsize ? boardTemp[i - 1, j + 1] : null;
                neighbours[3] = j > 0 ? boardTemp[i, j - 1] : null;
                neighbours[4] = j + 1 < boardsize ? boardTemp[i, j + 1] : null;
                neighbours[5] = i + 1 < boardsize && j > 0 ? boardTemp[i + 1, j - 1] : null;
                neighbours[6] = i + 1 < boardsize ? boardTemp[i + 1, j] : null;
                neighbours[7] = i + 1 < boardsize && j + 1 < boardsize ? boardTemp[i + 1, j + 1] : null;

                int i1 = i, j1 = j;
                threads[k] = new Thread(() => board[i1, j1] = new Field(boardTemp[i1, j1], neighbours));
                threads[k].Start();
                k++;
            }
        }

        // Wait for all the threads
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++)
        {
            threads[i].Join();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // Dispose the WaitForReady
        if (boardTemp != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < boardsize; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < boardsize; j++)
                {
                    if (boardTemp[i, j] != null)
                    {
                        boardTemp[i, j].Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The "trick" here is to create the `Field`s in 64 separate threads. When initialized first a `Field` "announce" itself to everyone (by setting its corresponding `WaitForReady<>` object), then it asks its neighbours for their `this` reference. It does this through the `WaitForReady<>` objects it receives as a parameters. The `WaitForReady<>` is a "special" container that can contain a single value (`Value`). If `Value` isn't set, then asking for it will put the thread in wait, until someone sets the value through the `set`.

For small sizes it is possible to build everything using recursion to simulate continuations. For a board size of 64 it is normally possible. This is faster.

```
public class Field
{
    public Field[] Neighbours;

    public Field(int i, int j, int boardsize, Func<Field>[,] getters)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Building [{0},{1}]", i, j);
        getters[i, j] = () => this;

        Neighbours = new Field[8];

        Neighbours[0] = i > 0 && j > 0 ? getters[i - 1, j - 1]() : null;
        Neighbours[1] = i > 0 ? getters[i - 1, j]() : null;
        Neighbours[2] = i > 0 && j + 1 < boardsize ? getters[i - 1, j + 1]() : null;
        Neighbours[3] = j > 0 ? getters[i, j - 1]() : null;
        Neighbours[4] = j + 1 < boardsize ? getters[i, j + 1]() : null;
        Neighbours[5] = i + 1 < boardsize && j > 0 ? getters[i + 1, j - 1]() : null;
        Neighbours[6] = i + 1 < boardsize ? getters[i + 1, j]() : null;
        Neighbours[7] = i + 1 < boardsize && j + 1 < boardsize ? getters[i + 1, j + 1]() : null;
        Console.WriteLine("Builded [{0},{1}]", i, j);
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int boardsize = 8;

    Field[,] board = new Field[boardsize, boardsize];
    Func<Field>[,] getters = new Func<Field>[boardsize, boardsize];

    for (int i = 0; i < boardsize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < boardsize; j++)
        {
            int i1 = i, j1 = j;
            getters[i, j] = () => board[i1, j1] = new Field(i1, j1, boardsize, getters);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < boardsize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < boardsize; j++)
        {
            getters[i, j]();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to let the Fields handle creation of the other fields.
It's gonna be a lot more work to write all the code, but it should be more processor efficient.

Turns out you can't do it in the constructor because you'll get into an infinite loop of fields trying to create each other (because they can't find each other yet).

I like doing things like aggressive inlining even though it only makes a tiny difference in Release mode and actually slows the code down in Debug mode. On my machine it was about .1 sec for 10k executions. Would be interested to know if that's any faster than @xanatos's answer. It's certainly a lot more code :P

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Algorithms
{
    public class Board
    {
        public Field[,] fields = new Field[8, 8];
    }

    public class Field
    {
        // Neighbor positions
        // 701  +1-1 +10  +1+1 
        // 6 2   0-1  00   0+1
        // 543  -1-1 -10, -1+1
        private Field[] neighbors = new Field[8];

        public void FindNeighbors(Board board, int rank, int file)
        {
            if (rank > 0)
            {
                // Not on bottom
                createNeighbor(board, rank - 1, file, 4);

                if (file > 0)
                {
                    // Not in bottom-left corner, so adding it
                    //createNeighbor(board, rank - 1, file, 4);
                    createNeighbor(board, rank - 1, file - 1, 5);
                    createNeighbor(board, rank, file - 1, 6);

                    if (rank < 7)
                    {
                        // Not on top corner, so adding above and left-above
                        createNeighbor(board, rank + 1, file - 1, 7);
                        createNeighbor(board, rank + 1, file, 0);

                        if (file < 7)
                        {
                            // Not in any corder, adding remainder
                            createNeighbor(board, rank, file + 1, 2);
                            createNeighbor(board, rank - 1, file + 1, 3);
                            createNeighbor(board, rank + 1, file + 1, 1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // On the right, the only fields that haven't been added yet are on the right
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // on top
                        if (file < 7)
                        {
                            // Not on the left, so add those fields.
                            createNeighbor(board, rank, file + 1, 2);
                            createNeighbor(board, rank - 1, file + 1, 3);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // On the top-left, so nothing else to add.
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    createNeighbor(board, rank, file + 1, 2);
                    createNeighbor(board, rank - 1, file + 1, 3);

                    if (rank < 7)
                    {
                        createNeighbor(board, rank + 1, file, 0);
                        createNeighbor(board, rank + 1, file + 1, 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Top-left corner, nothing to add
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Bottom
                createNeighbor(board, rank + 1, file, 0);

                if (file > 0)
                {
                    // Not on left
                    createNeighbor(board, rank, file - 1, 6);
                    createNeighbor(board, rank + 1, file - 1, 7);

                    if (file < 7)
                    {
                        // Not on the right
                        createNeighbor(board, rank + 1, file + 1, 1);
                        createNeighbor(board, rank, file + 1, 2);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Bottom-left corner
                    createNeighbor(board, rank + 1, file + 1, 1);
                    createNeighbor(board, rank, file + 1, 2);
                }
            }
        }

        // Neighbor positions
        // 701  +1-1 +10  +1+1 
        // 6 2   0-1  00   0+1
        // 543  -1-1 -10, -1+1
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        private void createNeighbor(Board board, int rank, int file, int neighbor)
        {
            var field = board.fields[rank, file];
            if (field == null)
            {
                field = new Field();
                board.fields[rank, file] = field;
                // Start looking for neighbors after their object is initialized.
                field.FindNeighbors(board, rank, file);
            }

            // Always copy a link to the field, even if it already existed
            neighbors[neighbor] = field;
        }
    }
}
```